# Sum of smalldatetime and format as decimal minutes SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

Working with an Access database, using SQL commands to pull data from it. I have a column 'Duration' formatted in smalldatetime, which contains data pertaining to the duration of a phone call. The data is this column is like so

```
0/01/1900  12:00:26 AM
```

This indicates a call that is 26 seconds in duration. (all start at 12:00:00 AM and work upwards)

I have a column called 'Extension' which identifies the user of the phone.

I am wanting to run a query that will show me total durations, but grouped by extensions.

The query I have so far is

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Duration,108)))), '00:00:00.000')),108)) as "timetest",
       Extension AS Extension
FROM BrendanTest GROUP BY Extension
```

This shows:

```
Timetest    Extension
00:12:00    117
00:06:00    118
```

which is correct.

However, I want to format the result, to show in decimal minutes, for example

```
00:04:56
```

would become

```
4.93
```

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: When you execute select distinct extension from brendantest what do you get?

Comment: Code working now @Sagi. Just need to know how to convert it to decimal minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming '00:04:56' is in the format HH:MM:SS, you can try something like the below to convert it to decimal format:

```
 SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('00:04:56',':','.'),3) * 60 --Convert the hours to minutes
        + PARSENAME(REPLACE('00:04:56',':','.'),2) --Add converted hours to minutes
        + CONVERT(FLOAT, LEFT((CONVERT(INT,(PARSENAME(REPLACE('00:04:56',':','.'),1)))/0.6),2))/100 -- convert to decimal format
```